# How to find out the username/identity of the user who is communicating with my bot (created using dialogflow)

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack

I'm totally new to dialogflow and have created and integrated an bot with slack.I'm clueless how to find the username of the person who has communicated with bot.
I've come across several codes but don't know exactly where to integrate the code.

Thanks in advance